# javascript: how to display script errors in a popup alert?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I want to display script errors in a popup alert instead of showing them in the browser console.

```
window.onerror = function() {
  var message = /* get error messages and put them here */;
  alert(message);
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Note that the `onerror` event is only supported by IE and Mozilla.

Comment: So is there a cross-browser solution? I mean, a similar function supported by webkit

Comment: You mean there are browsers other than IE and Mozilla??? Dang! I need to get out more :)

Comment: Actually it'll be supported (hopefully soon) in WebKit - see http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-lang-javascript/401318-window-onerror-chrome.html#post1867841

Comment: yep! But I got another problem. Seems that onerror only support those 3 parameters. There is no way to catch an error of a specific name.

Comment: `onerror` is useful for debugging. You should not be using it for production code. For catching errors the normal course of your scripts you should be using exceptions.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way.

See the reference here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error2.shtml

And explanation of how to see more details of the error here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error3.shtml

Their example:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
```

If you wish to display a LIST of errors in a single pop-up, it's trickier.

Since the errors occue 1 by 1, you need to do the following:

- have `window.onerror` handler store error details in some array
- Check that array periodically - either via a timer, or on every N'th call of `window.onerror` handler, or both.

  When the check happens, process entire array, display contents as desired, and empty out an array

Comment: Thx! So the answer is:
window.onerror = function(message) {
  alert(message);
  return true;
};

Just tested!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone would like to use it with jQuery:

```
$(window).on("error", function(evt) {

    console.log("jQuery error event:", evt);
    var e = evt.originalEvent; // get the javascript event
    console.log("original event:", e);
    if (e.message) { 
        alert("Error:\n\t" + e.message + "\nLine:\n\t" + e.lineno + "\nFile:\n\t" + e.filename);
    } else {
        alert("Error:\n\t" + e.type + "\nElement:\n\t" + (e.srcElement || e.target));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error3.shtml.  Looks like signature is `function(message, url, linenumber)`.