# Clarifying some javascript tasks I've been assigned

Tags: javascript

I have been given these two tasks. I’m not asking you to do the tasks for me; what I need is greater understanding.

> 1. Write JavaScript™ code that anticipates and handles an error for an expected numeric field. This code is executed on keypress, and the entered value is saved for you in a variable called `enteredChar`. Include the `try` block of JavaScript™ statements needed to check if the character is not a number or a non-alphanumeric character, or if you throw an error message.
> 2. Write a custom error handling JavaScript™ function called `processErrors` that handles a custom error by assigning it to the `onerror` event handler. Include the block of JavaScript™ statements needed to pass the arguments sent by the JavaScript™ interpreter into the `processErrors` function, send an alert message with the agreements, return, and write the event handler that calls the `processErrors` function.

What I am supposed to do? I am brand new to JavaScript and I am unsure what I have been asked to do.

I think the first one is asking me to write a code that stops anything but numbers and letters from running in the program?

The second one I think is asking me to code for some kind of error, but I am not sure what.

I am looking for clarification.

Comment: Yes and it is asking you to write a function that does validation and tells the user about the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unclear of what is being asked of you a good first step is to go back to who gave you the requirements and clarify them there.

Answer (score 1):

1. See [Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text).  So your going to listen to a text input field as you type, and then evaluate if the character is a number.  See [Check if character is number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935632/check-if-character-is-number).  They want you to wrap that in a try/catch.
2. They now want you to process the "catch" (the error) from number 1 called 'processErrors'.  See [how to catch ALL javascript errors with window.onerror? (including dojo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446861/how-to-catch-all-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-including-dojo).

Wow I almost managed to link everything back to stack overflow.  +10 ;)

Good luck

Comment: Ok, I am very much a beginner and I do not understand what you mean when you said "listen to a text input" or "wrap to try/catch"? Can you explain it a little better?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp  Good place to start anyway.

Comment: @Mark no, it's not. Mozilla Developer Network  should be used instead