# Show an alert or popup if a Javascript error occurs

Tags: javascript, error-handling, warnings

Is it possible to get visuel notifyed if I get a Javascript error?

In developing I have Firebug or something else open so I spot it. 
But in the case where I do a light demostration for someone else I can not have it open.

I still prefer to know about the error instead of it failing silently and I dont know about trailings errors where I can't distinct wish between real and trailing errors.

Comment: Just saw in the answer, might be a duplicate then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604976/javascript-how-to-display-script-errors-in-a-popup-alert/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround your code in a try-catch and call alert with the error message. For example, if your code is as follows:

```
var x = document.getElementById("wrong_id"); //returns null
x.innerHTML = "Hello world!"; //null exception
```

you can surround it with the try-catch as follows:

```
try {
    var x = document.getElementById("wrong_id"); //returns null
    x.innerHTML = "Hello world!"; //null exception
}
catch(err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
```

`err.message` basically contains the error message, similar to the one you see in Firebug.

**Edit**: You may also define `window.onerror`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604997/2825340)

Comment: Further help for the user: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I was looking where I don't have to wrap all my functions in try-catchs. So I could defined it one time one place. If it's possible. Ok i'll check window.onerror soon, it looks very promising

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use try catch functionality to show the error.

Something like this:

```
try {var a = 20 / f;}
catch (err) {alert(err);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magwalls/h7kqr/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But im sorry i forgot to mention that i wanted a higher abstractionlevel that try catch.