# Javascript: Which parameters are there for the onerror event with image objects? How to get additional details on an error related to an image?

Tags: javascript, image, object, parameters, onerror

I'm writing an application in JavaScript that should create a new image. Sometimes it fails. I was able to detect the times when it does by attaching an `image.onerror` event listener. Question is: How may I learn what error occured - what parameters does the error object for images bring? So far I only found out that

```
image.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
  console.log('Error: ' + errorMsg + ' Script: ' + url + ' Line: ' + lineNumber
  + ' Column: ' + column + ' StackTrace: ' +  errorObj);
}
```

which I got from:
[javascript: how to display script errors in a popup alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604976/javascript-how-to-display-script-errors-in-a-popup-alert)

returns `Error: [object Event] Script: undefined Line: undefined Column: undefined StackTrace: undefined` and in the error object I couldn't find anything related to message or error code.

Answer (score 15):

AFAIK the image.onerror handler will receive a single Event parameter that doesn't contain any info on the cause of the error.

Comment: MDN backing this up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#element.onerror

Answer (score 6):

Image.onerror comes with a handler rather than error message, url, ...

So, the first item in the list of arguments is an event.

If you try your code with

```
image.onerror(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
  console.log(errorMsg);
  console.log(url)
}
```

you should get an event for the first log and undefined for the second.

I haven't been able to locate any legit reference as to what comes with the onerous handler for an Image object. But looks like it is mostly used to flag the error to the user rather than the developer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to trap errors on a normal HTML `img` element (rather than dynamically creating one via the DOM), this seems to work well:

```
 <img src="http://yourdomain/site/badimage.png" 
      onerror="javascript:imageErrorHandler.call(this, event);"/>
```

Note that the `.call(this, event)` syntax is important so you have access to the `this` and `event` objects in your error handler.

Then you can define an image error handler like the following. (Make sure it is defined before the `img` element to avoid race conditions.) Assuming you have jQuery wired up:

```
 function imageErrorHandler(evt) {
    var $e = $(this);
    var src = $e.attr("src");
    console.log("Image URL '" + src + "' is invalid.");
 };
```

Tested this in Chrome. Have not tried other browsers.

Comment: This worked perfectly for finding a 404 image src taken from api.

Answer (score 2):

The exact results might depend a bit on the browser you're using, but you'll get one parameter only, the event. I guess the source you found was out-dated. I hacked this little JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lsag7pt6/ so you can try it yourself. Just comment in and out the correct and the "wrong" URL at the bottom of the script, open your JavaScript console (F12) and you'll see a print-out of the event with all it's attributes and values.

For reference, for the correct URL I get:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "load", target: img, currentTarget: img, eventPhase: 2…}
bubbles:false
cancelBubble:false
cancelable:false
composed:false
currentTarget:null
defaultPrevented:false
eventPhase:0
isTrusted:true
path:Array(6)
returnValue:true
srcElement:null
target:null
timeStamp:2109.725
type:"load"
```

Otherwise

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: img, currentTarget: img, eventPhase: 2…}
bubbles:false
cancelBubble:false
cancelable:false
composed:false
currentTarget:null
defaultPrevented:false
eventPhase:0
isTrusted:true
path:Array(7)
returnValue:true
srcElement:img
target:img
timeStamp:1189.805
type:"error"
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @svub, but the question is about creating an image in JavaScript, not about loading one from a URI that does or doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, seems like the others got that wrong as well. Ah, so the code generating the image might fail sometimes. Do you see anything like a stack trace in the JS console of your browser?