# Handling 404 inside Image.onerror when loading an image on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have written some Javascript code to load an image (uploaded by the end user) which looks as follows :

```
var img = new Image;
var ctx = _this.canvas.getContext('2d');
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  //do other stuff..    
}
img.onerror = function(event){
  bootbox.alert("Error loading the image!");
}
img.src = Settings.URL + '/images/loadimage/?imageKey=' + imageKey;
```

Server returns 404 response if the image corresponding to the `imageKey` does not exist, it also returns error 500 in other error scenarios.

This code works fine, but what I want to do is to show two different messages in the following two different cases:

1. When I get 404 response.
2. When Error 500 response.

What I am not able to figure out is - how to get response code in `img.onerror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [onerror method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#a-onerror) does not provide any information about the kind of error that occurred. Referring to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634509/2764486), "the `image.onerror` handler will receive a single Event parameter that doesn't contain any info on the cause of the error".

[In this blog post](https://blog.imagekit.io/how-to-handle-loading-images-that-may-not-exist-on-your-website-92e6c3c6ea63) you'll find some hints how to handle loading of images that may not exist. A quick solution in your case would be to load the image(s) with XMLHttpRequest where you have access to the network status:

```
let imageReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
imageReq.open("GET", Settings.URL + '/images/loadimage/?imageKey=' + imageKey, true);
imageReq.responseType = "blob";

imageReq.onload = function(imageEvent) {
  // the variable below will contain your image as BLOB data
  var blob = imageReq.response;

  let img = new Image;
  let ctx = _this.canvas.getContext('2d');

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    //do other stuff..    
  }

  let urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  let imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
  img.src = imageUrl;
};

imageReq.onreadystatechange = function (imageEvent) {  
  if (imageReq.readyState === 4) {  
    if (imageReq.status === 200) {  
      // image has been loaded correctly
    } else if (imageReq.status === 404) {  
      console.log("Image not found");  
    } else if (imageReq.status === 500) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", imageReq.statusText);
    }
  }  
};

imageReq.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and explanation, I tried the code and it worked in case of 404, but in case when the image actually exists, I got an error in this line : `img.src = blob;` `GET <My URL>/[object%20Blob] 404 (Not Found))` Please suggest.

Comment: I did some more google search and found the solution to the above problem.. it works when I replace line `img.src = blob;` in your code with lines : `var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob); img.src = imageUrl;` it works fine. I will accept your answer once you edit it accordingly. Thanks again

Comment: My mistake; I fixed the code. The blob must be converted into a URL before it can be accessed.