# Javascript errors are hidden in ASP.NET application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an `ASP.NET(4.5)` webform application which uses `JavaScript`.
And I am using `IE11`. The problem is if there is any error in this javascript(external file) nothing happens.

For example if I rename my file from a.js to b.js application continues running and nothing is showing in the IE.

Or In my code I had:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenWindow('.//Documents//TechnicalSupport.pdf');"  ..... >
```

And OpenWindow was not defined in the Javascript file so the link button was not working. From user perspective a click on the link did not do anything, no error messages or anything else.

The only way I can see it to press `F12` and see what happened(OpenWindow is not defined).

Question  : Is there any way to show the java script errors in the `ASP.NET` app? In above case I want to at least be able to log error "`OpenWindow  is not defined`"

Comment: Yes, you need to open the browser's debug console (F12).

Comment: have you tried the window.onerror event? window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    alert("Error occured: " + errorMsg);//or any message
    return false;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your question

> Is there any way to show the java script errors in the ASP.NET app?

Yes, [there is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604997/4773983):

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    //To show the error in the app
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    //To show the error in the Javascript console (Press F12)
    console.log('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
```

You can't access a file directly in JS, but you could access by WebService or check this [answer about PageMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083658/4773983) to Log the error in a file, just change the code in the static method

Comment: Yes I can access a file direcltly in the JS.::
`OpenWindow('.//Documents//TechnicalSupport.pdf');` Works without a problem

Comment: window.onerror only provides  error for window object. how about a case when calling a javascript function causes an error?

Comment: No, OpenWindow just open a file (PDF, in another cases it downloads the file) with the browser, but no write / read the file in JS. And to catch another code, use TryCatch blocks in your code (when calling a JS function)