# Show user-friendly error messages in Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As with any application a number of things can go wrong sooner or later. I have a large Vue application that sometimes throws some errors (I know, it shouldn't, but sometimes it does anyway) and I'd like to show a friendly message to the user so they won't be stuck waiting. Like a "generic error handler" of some kind on the window object.

I tried this: [javascript: how to display script errors in a popup alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604976/javascript-how-to-display-script-errors-in-a-popup-alert) but it does not fire.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect to a generic error page which displays an error ID and the message (if given).

A different way would be to display toasts and stay on the page, which will allow the user to retry actions. I recommend [vue-toasted](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted) for toasts in vue projects.

Comment: I could do a lot of things if the window.onerror event would fire. Including sending myself a text message, sending a wake-on-lan packet to my dev box, and turning on the espresso machine so I can get to work to fix whatever went wrong. But since the window.onerror event does not fire I get calls from users sometimes saying the page froze ("I've been waiting for it for the past 3 hours"). Thanks for the toasted tip, putting it on my to-do list.

Comment: You could just throw the errors when something breaks and then catch them in a error handler as described in my answer? 

Comment: As a last resort, yeah, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Throwing (and catching!) is a best practice. There's always something that could happen.