# Window.print() not working in ipad chrome in popup window[window.open()]

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my piece of code that work's in all the browser in all the OS, except ipad  chrome. Help me out here.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
   function myprint() {
    const wnd = window.open('about:blank', '', '_blank, alwaysRaised=yes');
    wnd.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    wnd.document.write('</head><body>');
    wnd.document.write('<div>JavaScript often abbreviated as JS, is a high-level, interpreted programming language. It is a language which is also characterized as dynamic, weakly typed, prototype-based and multi-paradigm.</div>');
    wnd.document.write('<div class="print-header"><button title="Print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button></div>');
    wnd.document.write('</body></html>');
    wnd.document.close();
  }
</script>
<body>
   <button onclick="myprint()">popup</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here Im trying to open my content using `window.open()` then print them using `window.print()`. That's all. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj72w15n/13/)

This link also not working in ipad chrome.
[Print](https://jsfiddle.net/jxr7uex6/11/)

Comment: document.write is NOT like building a string. closing tags are added automatically if you did not include them. So build the string and document.write once

Comment: I have tried your answer, it did'n, work. Browser doesn't mind when we use multiple document.write().

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Chrome on iOS. Because of Apple’s policy on third party browsers, Chrome is actually just a WebView component. Printing is currently not supported. As far as I am aware, there is currently no workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, if it not works another solution is to use a third-party printing service like this: http://www.printfriendly.com

```js
function goPrint(){
    window.print();
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a backtick character `` ` `` in this line:

```
wnd.document.write(`<div class="print-header"><button title="Print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button></div>`);
```

This is a [Templated literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and might not be supported. Try replacing it with a single quote:

```
wnd.document.write('<div class="print-header"><button title="Print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button></div>');
```

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. And also I tried your answer, still same result.

Comment: What does it print when you try the solution in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604997/4289700

Comment: Thanks for your response. error alert didn't work, alert box didn't even appear. I think browser does't take it as an error. Suggest me if you got any other way.